# Failed to apply plugin Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha5 must not be applied to project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Using the latest Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5

Here's the error:

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin']
>   Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha5 must not be applied to project [path_to_my_project] since version 3.0.0-alpha5 was already applied to this project

Tried: cleaning, rebuilding, opening/closing. Not working.

any ideas ?

**[LATER EDIT]**
Solution: Migrate to Canary 8+ and all should be ok.

Comment: facing this issue in only module dependency project. Normal gradle dependecy projects are working fine

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me.

Comment: Your solution should be an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6kjl8b/android_studio_30_canary_5_is_now_available/djmuv0o/), killing daemons fixed the problem for me.

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Comment: after stop the daemon, RESTART Android Studio. Now everything works fine ;)

Comment: Temporary fix it to set org.gradle.configureondemand=false and to kill the gradle deamon .

android studio, File->Invalidate Caches/Restart , works for me

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

**Deactivate [Configuration On Demand](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand)**

In `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

Then **stop the daemon** in a terminal window:

```
gradlew.bat --stop
```

Now everything works again.

Versions used:

- Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5
- gradle: `gradle-4.1-milestone-1`
- android gradle plugin: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5`

**UPDATE**
After upgrading to *Android Studio 3.0 **Beta 2*** I can reactivate *Configuration on Demand* and everything works fine.

Comment: You can also do it from the UI.  Go to Preferences -> Build, Execution, and Deployment -> Compiler, and uncheck "Configure on Demand".

Comment: how do i downgrade? its so annoying

Comment: You can download the older [Canary build](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html) that worked for you and reinstall it. I always make a copy before I upgrade - then it's just a matter of renaming folders.
Of course you must also restore your source code: e.g. gradle things may have changed, like the gradle version, android-gradle plugin, etc.

Comment: This doesnt work for me.  I had to change permissions of gradlew.bat for it to be executable, then when i ran `./gradlew.bat --stop` it gave me errors in the console.

Comment: @toobsco42 you should open a new question and link to it here, then we can have a look at your error output.

Comment: Don't forget to check `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating the gradle version from 3.0.0-alpha5 to 3.0.0-alpha7 saved my day !!

Answer (score 0):

#### Open a terminal and write

```
./gradlew --stop
```

#### In gradle.properties make sure you don't have funny stuff

Notice that there are no custom jvmargs...

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

#### Include the google() repo in build.gradle (project one)

there's how mine look like

#### *build.gradle*

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

  repositories {        
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:0.9.12.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### lastly the support library versions in the app build.gradle file

*build.gradle*

```
...
  //----- Support Libs
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
  implementation "com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2"
  implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2"
  implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue and realized the issue related with caches. 
You have to invalidate caches of Android studio by select **File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart.**
It worked for me. The issue was resolved.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I closed Android Studio and opened again, I noticed that it automatically applied these changes to the following files and everything worked fine:

**build.gradle**: changed the class path of Gradle from:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
```

to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
    }
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**: from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
```

Answer (score -3):

I already tried all the solutions including 
Clean,
Rebuild,
Invalidate Project

But nothing is working but i figured it out.

For temporary just downgrade your gradle plugin version to stable version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

Replace your alpha line with this line. And have fun.. :)

Comment: But there's no fun in 2.3.3 plugin :(

Comment: we're talking here the Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5 (latest...)