# Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin'] in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have installed latest Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5

Here's the error:

Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin'] Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha5 must not be applied to project [projectPath] since version 3.0.0-alpha5 was already applied to this project.

I have tried all solutions: cleaning, rebuilding, opening/closing, Invalidate caches. But it's not working.
Any solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858186/7806873 and solve your problem then delete it because possible duplicate.

Comment: I have tried. It's also not working.

Comment: Try with restart pc.

Comment: Accept as answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I run ./gradlew --stop command on terminal. then restart my laptop. It's working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

1) Kill the daemons by run this command in terminal:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

2) Then restart pc or laptop.